# Online shop - difference between reduced price and new price. Which one should be more visible?

Tags: e-commerce, behavioral-economics

New price = reduced price

Old price = old, bigger price

---

This is how i see the process:

1. See **New price**
2. Evaluate option to buy
3. See **Old price**
4. Evaluate option to buy with price difference as incentive.

--

1. See **Old price**
2. No need to evaluate option to buy - price not effective
3. See **New price**
4. Evaluate option to buy with price difference as incentive.

Based on my logic, emphasizing the reduced prize should get a better result. I mostly see in online shops this done the other way around, including Amazon. Why is it better the other to focus on the new smaller price?

Answer (score 1):

The price that is current wether it is a regular or reduced price is always the most important. That is what the user will pay. The regular pricing allows the user to know this may be a time limited sale, permanent discount or getting ready for clearance or to be discontinued as well as showing them how much of a discount they are getting. You should always lead with either the discount percentage, or the reduced price followed by the regular price. Your conversion rate will show which is more effective.